# Will std::string delete the char buffer allocated via new?

Tags: c++, string, memory, new-operator

Is here a memory leak?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A{
    std::string value;
public:
    A(){
        char *tmp = new char[3];
        tmp[0] = 'a';
        tmp[1] = 'b';
        tmp[2] = 'c';
        value = std::string(tmp);
    }
    std::string const& getValue() const {
        return value;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    std::cout << a.getValue() << '\n';
}
```

since the value is constructed from pointer to `new`ed memory, and thus the `std::string` is taking the ownership of it, will it also destroy? Or is it my responsibility to take care of that temporary object? And if so, the only way to destroying it is via having it as private variable, otherwise it goes out of scope (since the pointer is with auto storage created in constructor function).

So how is here the buffer managed?

Comment: "and thus the std::string is taking the ownership of it" what makes you think that? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @TheUndeadFish no, I don't know that, it is just my assumption

Comment: 99.9% of the time if you use `new`, it is your responsibility to make sure `delete` is called.  This example is in the 99.9%.  This is why unless you are writing really low level code, you should not be using `new`.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @NathanOliver but what if I get the char pointer from another function that malloced it (and thus I have no access for the buffer)

Comment: what this code suppose to do? What is wrong with: `value = "abc";` (which does same thing as your code, but without: memory leak, undefined behavior and boiler plate code)?

Comment: @MarekR the point was, I tried to replicate the error I got. I used `uuid_unparse` which gives char pointer generated from malloc (see its documentation), but in class handling uuid I had std::string. And since the std::string does not have ownership, I had to change the implementation of the class to handle char pointers only

Comment: The is the reason I asked a situation where you get the pointer, and you are not the owner of the buffer... I did not know, how to handle this situation

Comment: So basically you are asking wrong question! Apparently you are using this function in wrong way.

Comment: @MarekR the uuid API is for C usage. I don't know about C++ library for UUID support, except of boost which I am not willing to use

Comment: @milanHrabos I've provide answer with proper use of `uuid_unparse`.

Comment: @milanHrabos please note, that your question doesn't reflect your actual problem. This is quite common problem when someone begins asking technical questions. So common that there is term describing it: [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should note this to avoid it next time.

Answer (score 3):

> thus the `std::string` is taking the ownership of it

This assumption is incorrect. `std::string` doesn't take ownership of any pointer, constructor taking `char*` copies the data into internal storage. So yes, you have to `delete[]` what you `new[]`'ed.

---

Also, if you are passing `char*` to `std::string`, it must be null terminated:

```
    A(){
        char *tmp = new char[4];
        tmp[0] = 'a';
        tmp[1] = 'b';
        tmp[2] = 'c';
        tmp[3] = '\0';
        value = std::string(tmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. I mean imagine if it did and you did this (ignoring the missing 0)

```
    char *tmp = new char[3];
    tmp[0] = 'a';
    tmp[1] = 'b';
    tmp[2] = 'c';
    std::string value1 = std::string(tmp);
    std::string value2 = std::string(tmp);
```

You would be very upset if the second string creation failed

Also `std::string(const char*s)` cannot tell that the memory for `s` is on the heap, stack or static. All it can see is a pointer. Even if it wanted to steal the memory it has no way of knowing if its doable

Comment: Even if the memory is on the heap it does not know if it was allocated via malloc or new[].

Answer (score 2):

> And thus the std::string is taking the ownership of it, will it also destroy?

If you take ownership of a resource, that means that you will eventually release the resource (unless you transfer it to some other owner, and unless the ownership is shared). If you don't release the resource (or the mentioned exceptions apply), then either you have not taken ownership, or you have a bug.

`std::string` will only delete a buffer that `std::string` has created. `std::string` will not take ownership of a buffer that you have created. Your assumption of *"std::string is taking the ownership"* is wrong.

Never try to guess whether some function / constructor takes ownership or not. Always rely on documentation to find that out.

> Or is it my responsibility to take care of that temporary object?

Yes. You are responsible for freeing the allocations that you create (until you transfer the onwership to something like a smart pointer).

The dynamic allocation that you created leaks, because you don't deallocate it.

> And if so, the only way to destroying it is via having it as private variable, otherwise it goes out of scope

You can simply delete it after the `std::string` has been created and thus your buffer is no longer used.

**Important!** `std::string` constructor that accepts `char*` requires that the pointed string is null terminated. Your string doesn't contain the null terminator character, and thus the call violates the precondition. The behaviour of your program is undefined.

Furthermore, the allocation is entirely unnecessary. You can achieve the intended behaviour and fix both the undefined behaviour and the memory leak by writing the constructor like this:

```
A(): value("abc") {}
```

> but what if I get the char pointer from another function that malloced it

Primarily, try to avoid calling such functions.

But in case you have no other option, then you must understand that the function is transferring the ownership of the allocation to you (I cannot think of any other reason the function would document that it used `std::malloc`). You must deallocate it using `std::free` once you no longer need it. Ideally, you should use something like a smart pointer to do so.

> I used uuid_unparse which gives char pointer generated from malloc (see its documentation)

According to the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uuid_unparse.3.html) of `uuid_unparse`, it doesn't do such thing. It doesn't allocate anything. If you want to use it with `std::string`, you can do this:

```
uuid_t some_uuid = example_uuid();
constexpr std::size_t uuid_size = 36;
std::string str(uuid_size, '\0');
uuid_unparse(some_uuid, str.data());
```

Answer (score 0):

The 5th constructor explained in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) takes the `char*` argument. It means it takes the pointer pointing the c-style string, calculates its length and then converts to `std::string`. The memory of original c-style `char*` string isn't released, so you have memory leak unless you later `delete` the `char*` string somewhere in code.

Answer (score 0):

Most interesting comment:

> @MarekR the point was, I tried to replicate the error I got. I used
> `uuid_unparse` which gives char pointer generated from malloc (see its
> documentation), but in class handling uuid I had std::string. And
> since the std::string does not have ownership, I had to change the
> implementation of the class to handle char pointers only –
> milanHrabos

Apparently you are using [uuid_unparse](https://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid_unparse) with c++ in wrong way and when problem appeared you asked question which do not reflect actual problem.

I would use this API in following way:

```cpp
std::string uuid_to_string(uuid_t uu)
{
    char buff[37];
    uuid_unparse(uu, buff);
    return buff; // implicit conversion to std::string is done here.
}
```

or more fancy way to do it:

```cpp
std::string uuid_to_string(uuid_t uu)
{
    std::string buff(size_t{36}, '\0');
    uuid_unparse(uu, buff.data()); // since C++17 data returns `char *`
    return buff;
}
```

---

About your code:

```cpp
        char *tmp = new char[3];
        tmp[0] = 'a';
        tmp[1] = 'b';
        tmp[2] = 'c';
        value = std::string(tmp);
```

this has 3 issues:

1. you are allocating memory which is not freed (string doesn't take over ownership of it) - so memory leak
2. your buffer do not contain terminating zero, so when it is passed to `std::string` this leads to undefined behavior since and of string can't be determined
3. code is simply over-complicated. After understudying what was its purpose I was able to provide simple solution.